# Cloud function finished with status: 'connection error' for large files

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I have a Google Cloud Function that reads multi-line file from Cloud Storage and writes back to Cloud Storage as a single line file with delimiter.

Below code works well for small files but in case of huge file (150 MB) it stops with status: 'connection error'.

I make use of `createReadStream` and `createWriteStream` as mentioned in the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.4.x/File#createWriteStream).

**Note:** I have hard coded input file name for testing

index.js

```
const fs = require('fs')
const readline = require('readline');
const byline = require('byline');
const storage = require('@google-cloud/storage')();
const stream = require('stream');

exports.processFiles = function(event, callback) {
const bucket = storage.bucket('src_bucket');
const targetbucket = storage.bucket('cf100');
const remoteFile = bucket.file('/files/mylog.log');


const outremoteFile = targetbucket.file('processed_log.log');

var line_no = 1;
var segmentsLineCheck = ["s1", "s2", "s3"];
var segments = [];

var  gcsStream = remoteFile.createReadStream();



let remoteWriteStream = outremoteFile.createWriteStream({ resumable: false,
     metadata : { 
        contentType : 'text/plain'  
     }
  }); 


var lineStream = byline.createStream(gcsStream);
lineStream.on('data', function(line) {
 transform(line.toString()); 
});

lineStream.on('error', (err) => {
            console.log('lineStream Err'+err);
        });

lineStream.on('finish', () => {
    remoteWriteStream.end();
            console.log('lineStream finished' );
        });


var isSegmentStarted = false;
var segmentString = '';
var segmentFound = '';

function transform(line) {

    //if line contains any of the segmentsLineCheck then add the line to segments array
    //else append the line followed by $$

    if (new RegExp(segmentsLineCheck.join("|")).test(line)) {
        // At least one match in segmentsLineCheck

        for(var i=0; i<segmentsLineCheck.length; i++) {
            if(line.indexOf(segmentsLineCheck[i])!==-1) {
                segmentFound = segmentsLineCheck[i];
                segmentsLineCheck.splice(i, 1);
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!isSegmentStarted) {
            console.log('segment forund - ' , segmentFound);
            console.log('segments remaining - ' , segmentsLineCheck);

            segmentString = ' $$ ' + line;
            isSegmentStarted = true;
        }
    } else if(line.indexOf('[20')!==-1 && isSegmentStarted) {
        remoteWriteStream.write(line+ ' $$ '); 
        isSegmentStarted = false;
        if(segmentString!=='') { 
            segments[segments.length] = segmentString;
            segmentString = ''; 
        }   
    } else if(isSegmentStarted) {
        segmentString += line;
    } else if(!isSegmentStarted){
        remoteWriteStream.write(line+ ' $$ ');
    }

    line_no++;

}
callback();
};
```

Comment: I have tried to reproduce your issue using your code but I get “Ignoring exception from a finished function” both for small and big files. I have never encountered a “connection error”. 

Could you update the post adding the package.json? So I can ensure that we are using the same libraries. What file sizes have you tested so far? I would like to know when the file is big enough to trigger the “connection error”.

Comment: @RubénC. Yes, this works well even for large files. Actually the issue is with the file I tried to process. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in this post works well for both small and large files. The issue I faced was due to incorrect file. I have this post untouched so that it helps someone else.

Comment: Could you please share more details as to what "incorrect file" means? What was the problem?

Comment: @VicSeedoubleyew The code looks for delimiter such as s1,s2,s3 from my input file but since I passed a wrong file which do not contain these delimiters it lead to hold entire file in memory. Thus the error.

Comment: thanks for the answer! So you mean that the error was that the Google Cloud Function reached its memory limit?

Comment: In this case error could be related to memory limit.